# What does "[::]" in Netstat on Windows indicate?

Tags: windows, cmd, netstat

In connection with this [Why am I getting, "Unable to connect to the remote server"? problem, I ran "Netstat -na" in cmd.exe, to make sure the server that is running is really seen as actually running.

I see an entry with the port number in it:

```
[::]:28642      [::]:0      LISTENING
```

...but what is this "[::]:" jazz?

Do these Picaso-esque dominos indicate a problem, or...???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a non-routable IPv6 meta-address that specifies "all interfaces", similar to 0.0.0.0 in IPv4. In this case it's listening on all registered local IPv6 addresses on port 28642.

Comment: Why would it do that - why would it not just listen to a particular IP address?

Comment: Often you don't care what interface you listen on - you just want to listen for requests on any and all interfaces. For example, with something like SMB (the protocol that Windows file shares use) you'd want to be able to access the shares no matter which interface you're plugged into, so the machine would listen on 0.0.0.0:445 (or [::]:445 for IPv6) rather than on one specific address allocated to a NIC.